# Swift Button That Outputs UICollectionView Cells One by One?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I made a UICollectionView, and everything is working. It makes 100 cells that I can scroll through in simulator with no problem.

However, rather than seeing all the cells at once, I want the cells to be released one by one whenever that red button is pressed.

I am confused because I noticed in the storyboard, it hard codes the number of cells it has on the screen at once. Is there any way to get around this?

Thank you!

[This is what the UI looks like in storyboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCO0i.jpg)

[This is the code I used to make it. It's basic, and just says to fill the text box of the cell with a string from the array.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xodPh.jpg)

Comment: Everyone gave a ton of useful info, and I definitely learned a lot!  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "I want the cells to be released one by one whenever that red button is pressed"? Are you saying that you want the collection view to start out empty, and each time you click the "+" button, you add a cell? Do you want it to stop at some maximum number of cells? 100 cells? It would probably be quite painful to have to tap the button 100 times if you wanted the 100th cell.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. It's for a tabletop card game- you're not supposed to see all the cells at once. 

Right now, each card has a task to do on your turn. If you can't do it, you swipe left to delete it, and it pops up with a new one in its place. That's the code I have so far, but again, I need to improve it so the cards are hidden until the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is garbled.

A collection view has a delegate and a data source. The data source responds to messages in the `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol. That protocol lets the collection view ask how many sections it has, and how many rows in each section, as well as asking for the cells from those sections and rows.

There are also methods that let you tell the table view that you want to add more cells. Take a look at the method `insertItems(at:)`. That lets you provide an array of indexPaths, which tells the table view that you have added new entries.

You could certainly write a button action method that added one or more entries to your data model and then used the `insertItems(at:)` method to notify the collection view that it had new entries. If there was room in the content view of the collection view to display additional cells it would then call the data source and ask for new cells at those index paths.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to keep track of how many items you want displayed (which will increase the more that button is pressed) and use that in your UICollectionViewDataSource method. Something like:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return min(myRunningItemCount, maximumNumberOfItems) //assuming there's a maximum
}
```

Then you just need to call reloadData on the collection view whenever that number changes.

Comment: You didn't tell the OP how to notify the collection view that you've added more cells. The "Brute force" method would be to simply call reloadData, but its better and more efficient to use one of the methods that let you add/modify just the indexPaths that you are changing. (See my answer.)